# Find out in which activity fragment was added

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

So basically I'm using same type of fragment in two different activities and I want to create and initialize some variable in the fragment only if it was added from specific activity. My question is how can I programmatically find out in which activity the fragment was added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there're two main ways of achieving it:

the less modular approach, you simply check using `instanceof`

```
if(getActivity() instanceof MyActivity)
```

and the more modular approach, you pass some arguments to the fragment on the moment you'll add it to the transaction:

```
// this during the transaction to pass extra parameters to the fragment
Fragment f = new MyFragment();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putBoolean("doExtraCode", true);
f.setArguments(b);
```

then inside the fragment:

```
// check if should execute extras
Bundle b = getArguments();
boolean doExtraCode = b == null? false: b.getBoolean("doExtraCode", false);
```

Comment: I like the second solution far more than the first.  Fragments should as much as possible be independent of the activities that host them (it's kind of the point of using fragments).

Comment: I totally agree with @BobbyStJacques the "more modular approach" is always better in absolutely any coding situation. I only shown the first one for completeness.